# Lettering on Blender - PBR Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

I would like to know why the material stays in the edges of the object. I first converted the text from the blender to the curve and then converted it to an object, I took the UV map in several ways to try to soften these breaks but still this problem continues, could anyone tell me how I can do this?[image]

Comment: I know that if you change the Image Texture's 2DTexture Method (3rd drop-down button on the Image Texture Node) to Box, you get a Blend option that will blend together the edges of the box. This may work for your letter or not, thus me not posting this as an answer.